# UICollectionView with custom layout - unable to add supplementary view in storyboard

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

From the [Collection View Programming Guide for IOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCellsandViews/CreatingCellsandViews.html):

---

### Registering Your Cells and Supplementary Views

You can configure the cells and views of your collection view programmatically or in your app’s storyboard file.

- **To configure cells and views in your storyboard:**

  When configuring cells and supplementary views in a storyboard, you do so by dragging the item onto your collection view and configuring it there. This creates a relationship between the collection view and the corresponding cell or view.

  - For cells, drag a Collection View Cell from the object library and drop it on to your collection view. Set the custom class and the collection reusable view identifier of your cell to appropriate values.
  - For supplementary views, drag a Collection Reusable View from the object library and drop it on to your collection view. Set the custom class and the collection reusable view identifier of your view to appropriate values.

---

There is no way that I manage to drop a Collection Reusable View unto a collection view in my storyboard as long as layout is set to Custom instead of Flow. If I drop one when layout is set to flow, it's gone as soon as I set Layout back to custom.

If I drop it outside of the collection view, as a top level object, it's not used at runtime, even though both the class and identifier is set right. Instead I get an error telling me that I have to register the supplementary view. If I register it manually, it want use my visual design from the storyboard.

Any suggestions on how this is ment to work?

Comment: I found that same thing as you did with trying to add the CollectionViewReusableView in a storyboard with a custom layout. Have you tried making your view in a xib file and registering the nib?

Comment: Nope. I just replaced it with code all together.

Answer (score 11):

**You can do this only if your layout is a subclass of UICollectionViewFlowLayout.**

> 1. Don't specify custom layout in storyboard.
> 2. Select flow layout and design your supplementary view.
> 3. Then in your viewcontroller programmatically create and assign your new layout
>      object to collectionview.
> 4. Call InvalidateLayout on your layout object
> 5. Use the supplementary view you designed in storyboard with your custom layout

**This has worked for me. Hope it helps anybody else too !**

Comment: This seems the easiest way to work around the problem. Works for me!

Comment: If your custom layout is a subclass of a UICollectionViewFlowLayout, open storyboard editor and select flow layout (yellow cube) in the left object list under Collection View object. Then in "Identity Inspector" select your descendant class. That's it. No code change required.

Comment: @adnako thanks for the comment. This saved me deleting my fairly complex flow layout subclass. LOL!

Answer (score 5):

***You cannot add supplementary views to the storyboard with custom layout***. The supplementary views are managed by the layout object. Only layout knows its position,number.. It is not necessary to implement supplementary views by the layout object. It is the concern of layout object. `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` is provided with supplementary views(section header/footer). So you can design it in the storyboard. If you are using custom layout, how the storyboard knows whether it supports supplementary views. So it will give that job to you. ***You have to register the class/nib for the supplementary views***.

Comment: I disagree with the reasoning. The `registerClass:forSupplementaryViewOfKind:withReuseIdentifier:` method belongs to `UICollectionView`, not `UICollectionViewLayout`. The collectionview knows nothing about what supplementary views a layout supports or not, and the kind-spesifier is just a string, so you can register classes for supplementary views that the layout knows nothing about. So why shouldn't you be able to do the same in a storyboard? Add a `UICollectionReusableView` and specify its kind?

Comment: The only reason for registering the class is for the collectionview to be able to create a view for you if there is no view to dequeue. This contrast with the `UITableView` where the registering is optional. When you say 'The supplementary views are provided by the layout object' - its wrong. The layout will not provide any views. It will only tell where the view should be. It's all up to the `UICollectionView` and its`UICollectionViewDataSource` protocol to provide the view.

Comment: registering a reusable view in storyboard is not a problem. How the storyboard knows your custom layout support the supplementary views? If it supports where to place it?? Then how many number of supplementary views?

Comment: If you select flow layout, the postion and number is fixed. You can design accordingly.

Comment: If iam wrong you can correct me, i just added my thoughts. Design a non existing thing(may be exists but no idea about)in storyboard makes no sense.

Comment: I don't think you're wrong in that it's not possible as of today. I think you're wrong in that it couldn't be possible and won't make sense. When dropping a view as a top-level object, you can design it visually. You can drop buttons and labels and stuff, and connect it to outlets without regards to where this view will later be displayed. That's up to the layout to decide. But when I choose to use a custom layout, I better know what supplementary views it supports, so why would I create views not supported? All I want is a way of visually design it together with the rest.

Comment: The documentation contradicts the assertion. I'd say this is a clear bug within the storyboard designer. Yes, the layout manager controls the layout of the elements, but there are a lot of features of this elements I'd like to design visually. The documentation indicates that you can drag and drop the collection reusable view, but in a custom layout you can't, and in a flow layout you can only drag and drop two, the header and footer.

Answer (score 1):

This comment from the current top answer seems to be the best solution.

> If your custom layout is a subclass of a UICollectionViewFlowLayout, open storyboard editor and select flow layout (yellow cube) in the left object list under Collection View object. Then in "Identity Inspector" select your descendant class. That's it. No code change required
>
> - adnako